# How to add an element to multi-dimensional JSON array if the element key is a variable

Tags: javascript, json

There is a JSON file with an array like

```
{
    "general_array":[
        {"key_1":["a","b","c"]}
    ]
}
```

I want to add an element to the array e.g.

```
{"key_2":["d","e","f"]}
```

but the value of new key I get from a variable e.g.

```
var newKey = 'key_2';
```

I'm trying to add the element to the existed array as following

```
// ... getting file content
// var jsonFileContent = '{"general_array":[{"key_1":["a","b","c"]}]}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFileContent);

var newKey = 'key_2';

jsonObj.general_array.push({newKey:['d','e','f']});

var newJsonFileContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

// and rewrite the file ...
// console.log(newJsonFileContent);
```

But in the file I get

```
{
    "general_array":[
        {"key_1":["a","b","c"]},
        {"newKey":["d","e","f"]}
    ]
}
```

i.e. as the new element key I get the NAME of variable, but I need its VALUE

How to add the value?

---

**UPDATED**

The solution with `[newKey]` works in most of browsers, but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11

I need a solution to be working in IE11 too, so the question is still actual

Comment: `jsonObj.general_array.push({[newKey]:['d','e','f']});`

Comment: You're looking for the `[ ]` syntax.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your last update. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `[newKey]` to get the value of the variable as a key name:

```js
var jsonFileContent = `
{
    "general_array":[
        {"key_1":["a","b","c"]}
    ]
}`;
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFileContent);

var newKey = 'key_2';

var tempObj = {};
tempObj[newKey] = ['d','e','f'];
jsonObj.general_array.push(tempObj);

var newJsonFileContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
console.log(newJsonFileContent);
```

Comment: Oh, looks like it doesn't work in IE11. Is there a workaround for the browser?

Comment: @stckvrw updated the answer. It should work in IE now.

Answer (score 2):

To use the value of a variable as a JSON key, enclose it in square brackets, like so:

```
{[newKey]:['d','e','f']}
```

```js
let jsonFileContent = '{"general_array":[{"key_1":["a","b","c"]}]}';

let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFileContent);

let newKey = 'key_2';

jsonObj.general_array.push({[newKey]:['d','e','f']});

let newJsonFileContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

console.log(newJsonFileContent)
```

This is the [computed property name syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).  It's a shorthand/syntax sugaring for `someObject[someKey] = somevalue`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line:

```
jsonObj.general_array.push({newKey:['d','e','f']});
```

For this:

```
var newObj = {};
newObj[newKey] = ['d','e','f'];
jsonObj.general_array.push(newObj);
```